# Query on a row which returns the column that the data occurs in and all the columns before it

Tags: sql

Hi i have a table and when i query for a row i want to know which column a specific data appears in

```
                        TABLE
            | A1 | A2 | A3 | A4 | A5 | ID |
              QA    W    E    R    T    1
               Y    U    I   QA    O    2
               G    H   QA    U    T    3
```

So for example when i query for table where ID=1 i want to know which column QA occurs in and all the columns before it, a data in a single row will never appear twice.

example

```
         Select * from table where ID=1
                | A1 | ID |
                  QA    1

         Select * from table where ID=2
           | A1 | A2 | A3 | A4 | ID |
             Y     U    I   QA   2
```

Im thinking of maybe using a case statement 5 times for each column, but i dont know how to create a different select statement after the THEN clause inside the case statement. so is it something like

```
    select case when A3 = 'QA' then select A1,A2,A3 from table where ID = 1)
```

?
Thanks

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but goes to a root of your question. In databases, column order is really an arbitrary concept. A table design should never be dependent on the columns being in a specific order.

Comment: ah i didnt mean to get columns before it, more like get the column header whose number is below it, so A4 will be able to retrieve A3 A2 A1 and so on

Comment: You can use a set of or - for eample WHERE id =1 AND(A1='QA' or A2 = 'QA')

Comment: That makes more sense. What programming language are you using?

Comment: SQL and C#, i like to use SQL to deal with data handling and C# to just load whatever SQL gives, i heard of LINQ to query data within C# before but not sure how to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of options. Essentially, you need to unpivot your columns so that you can get the values. And you can use a CTE to filter your results for your needed criteria. You can either use T-SQL's `UNPIVOT` or a `CROSS APPLY` (which is likely faster and probably gives a slightly cleaner query plan).

Given your data:

**CROSS APPLY EXAMPLE:**

```
; WITH myList AS (
  SELECT t1.ID, ca.ColName, ca.Val
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.ID ORDER BY ca.ColName) AS rn
  FROM t1
  CROSS APPLY (
      VALUES 
        ('Row_1', A1)
      , ('Row_2', A2)
      , ('Row_3', A3)
      , ('Row_4', A4)
      , ('Row_5', A5)
    ) ca(ColName, Val)
  WHERE t1.ID = 2
)
, myPicks AS (
    SELECT ID, ColName, Val, rn
    FROM myList
    WHERE Val = 'QA'
)
SELECT l.ID, l.ColName, l.Val
FROM myList l
INNER JOIN myPicks p ON l.ID = p.ID
    AND l.rn <= p.rn
```

**UNPIVOT EXAMPLE:**

```
; WITH myList AS (
  SELECT unpiv.ID, unpiv.ColName, unpiv.Val
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY unpiv.ID ORDER BY unpiv.ColName) AS rn
  FROM t1
  UNPIVOT 
  (
      Val 
      FOR ColName IN ( A1, A5, A3, A2, A4 )
  ) unpiv
  WHERE unpiv.ID = 2
)
, myPicks AS (
    SELECT ID, ColName, Val, rn
    FROM myList
    WHERE Val = 'QA'

)
SELECT l.ID, l.ColName, l.Val
FROM myList l
INNER JOIN myPicks p ON l.ID = p.ID
    AND l.rn <= p.rn
```

...will give you...

```
ID  ColName Val
2   A1      Y
2   A2      U
2   A3      I
2   A4      QA
```

This will put your data in rows which may be easier to work with in your programming language to re-pivot the way you need it. I'm not really sure how you plan on using this code or how your C# will work with it. That could change the best way to get at it.

Regardless, a column list in SQL isn't necessarily guaranteed to come back in a specific order, and as was previously mentioned, column order should not be relied upon. The current behavior of a `PIVOT`/`UNPIVOT` will currently order the "columns" in the order that you put them in the `IN` clause, but that's not documented behavior and can change at any update. The most reliable way for ordering in SQL is to use an `ORDER BY` clause. You can alias the columns you are unpivoting (but it requires more work), or just assign an alias as one of the values in the `CROSS APPLY`.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2ee6086ef661901542ba4d7a6b20181f

Comment: NOTE: If one of your columns contains a `null`, the `UNPIVOT` will drop it from the results, but the `CROSS APPLY` will keep it.

Comment: Thanks the result set looks very easy to work with bu the sql query is abit too advanced for me:(, since you said unpivot will drop the results i think i will use that instead as there will be null values in my tables, im actually using it as sort of a access level, the people at the lower columns will not be able to see the people at the higher columns

Comment: @guyguy If you want to exclude `null` values, you can modify the first CTE in the `CROSS APPLY` to filter `WHERE ca.val IS NOT NULL`. Depending on how many total rows are in your table, the `CROSS APPLY` will probably be a bit faster than the `UNPIVOT`. It will also give you a bit more flexibility in ordering the column names.

Comment: I also created a new Fiddle that steps through the process and talks about some of the features I employed. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=240d6b8e944fd7632fe3eccc7977d682